# Show some content to User in Xamarin WebView

Tags: xamarin, webview, xamarin.forms, uwp

We are working with **Xamarin** application and using **WebView**. Defining a source is a website address of **WebView**. And we want to show only About-Us content and hide other clickable links of **WebView** in Xamarin UWP.

**Code**:

`<WebView x:Name="webView"  Source="https://www.website.com/about-us/" Grid.Row="0" 
Navigating="WebView_OnNavigatingebOnNavigating" Navigated="WebView_OnNavigatedebOnEndNavigating"/>`

Comment: Basically your web view is the same as a basic browser view. What is does is it opens a url and displays the html content it finds there.

Either you need to put a modified version of that website on the webserver and open that Source="https://www.website.com/about-us-nolinks/" or you add that html content to your app resources and open that.

Comment: You would need to download the html first, remove what you do not want and then load the remaining html in the WebView

Comment: @SushilHangover: It doesn't resolve my purpose. In future the About Us content would be changed on WebSite then I need to change again in my App. That I don't want to. It should refer to the same Content as on WebSite.

Comment: @MarkusMichel: Is there any other solution that resolves my problem, without changing in Website.?

Comment: Maybe you can dig into the webview's event handlers and override them to catch any navigation events and block handling, however that would still make your navigation elemets visible, though unnavigatable.

Allow me to fabricate a question, which would be an analogy to what you want: "Is there a command line parameter to open chrome with so it doesn't display the google logo and the search field on google" - I fear the answer to that is simply: NO, there isn't.

Comment: In theory, you could create a javascript, that gets injected into the site after it has been loaded and remove the elements in the DOM tree of the page with it. However, I have no Idea if it that is possible at all or if you can adapt a webview to enable such a behavior.

Comment: In terms of "work needed to achieve the desired result", you should probably ask your web guy to create a version of that page for the app.